# Access webservice on Jelastic

Tags: web-services, glassfish, jelastic

I'm trying access a web service on Glassfish 3 on Jelastic, but Glassfish always displays HTTP Status 404. I've tried some URLs, but without any success. Webservice is deployed correctly - I can see it in log:

[#|2014-07-10T14:52:53.414+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.webservices.org.glassfish.webservices|_ThreadID=75;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WS00019: EJB Endpoint deployed
 myapp  listening at address at `http://glassfishx.x.x.x.x.xxxxx.env-xxx:28080/MyWebService/MyWebService`|#]

I can access the application using URL `http://env-xxxxxx.jelastic.dogado.eu/myapp`, but not the webservice. 
The webservice is implemented as stateless sessionbean.

On my local glassfish the webservice wsdl is accessible with URL `http://localhost:8080/MyWebService/MyWebService?WSDL`.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Michal

Comment: Do you have public IP enabled on this GlassFish server?

Comment: I can see Glassfish welcome page and also I can use my web application, so I think Glassfish has public IP. Only my webservice is not accessible. Or do you think something else?

Comment: I've got it... it looks like Jelastic Glassfish has problems with WS as Stateless beans. Removing @Stateless and webservice works.

Comment: I thought your issue may have been port access related; without public IP your traffic is proxied via the Jelastic Resolver so only ports 80/443 are accessible. If you add public IP you connect direct instead, so any ports or protocols are available.